# SQL: does the order of GROUP BY conditions matter?

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-order-by

My understanding is, the expressions passed to `GROUP BY` can have any order because the aggregation functions just consider the combination of the columns when accumulating.

This is different than `ORDER BY` when the first column is sorted out before the second and so on.

Are the above sentences correct?

Comment: Unless you use the `WITH ROLLUP` option to make subtotals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In any database but MySQL, your statement would be correct without additional comment.  MySQL -- with deprecated functionality -- returns the result set in the order specified by the `group by`.  Let me repeat that this is deprecated and you should not depend on the functionality, but it is there and has been used.

In terms of the functionality of `group by` this makes little difference.  You will get the same groups with the same calculated values for each group.  The ordering of the result set might differ -- but the `group by` does not return an ordered result set unless you use `oder by`.

Comment: What matters most is the behavior of the aggregating functions like how `COUNT` would be affected if the values are switched.

Comment: @rahmanisback . . . There should be no effect.  The groups are assigned the same way.

Comment: MySQL has an "extension" to GROUP BY which permits what I describe a "lazy syntax" such that with this "extension" on, the non-aggregating columns of the select clause do not have to be present in the group by clause. Consequently the results are "indeterminate" for those non-aggregating columns omitted from the group by clause. In short; be wary of MySQL's group by. see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-handling.html